# How to get AWS SQS ReceiptHandle from Elastic Beanstalk worker?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

One of AWS's published message handling patterns suggests using a message ReceiptHandle in order to extend it's visibility timeout, but I've discovered that when consuming messages in an Elastic Beanstalk worker (via aws-sqsd), the ReceiptHandle is not passed as one of the header parameters.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get the ReceiptHandle for a message?

Thanks.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do this?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to get this information, so I have to make do with another, poorer, method. But what do you mean? I know that EB does not provide this data, but I don't understand why, no. I know that sqsd is handling the delivery and deletion of messages, but that should not preclude at all the ability to lengthen the visibility timeout.

Comment: `sqsd` was not designed for that. It seems that you need a custom solution and EB is not the right tool for your use-case.

Comment: There's an [open issue for this in github](https://github.com/aws/elastic-beanstalk-roadmap/issues/190) - please upvote it to encourage the maintainers to add this feature!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly you can't do this. EB worker does not provide that for you by default. The retrieval and deletion of msgs from SQS is **managed by EB sqs daemon**, not your application.

This simplifies deployments as you don't have to worry about interacting with SQS, but then limits what you can do.